# If file does not exist, create it and write string to it. If it does then append string to it. Isn't working right

Tags: android, file, append, filewriter, file-exists

Okay, I read a lot and thought I had this worked out but apparently not. What I'm trying to do is check to see if a file exists (in this case heapFile.csv) and if it doesn't to create it and then write a string to it. If the file does exist, then I want to append the string to the file. I get no errors when I run this though I do get a warning saying that it can't create the file although it actually does do so. However it's not writing the string to the file in either case. I'm probably just not using the right syntax or something but after staring at this for weeks I can't see the forest for the trees and find the problem. Aside from this one issue my program is working fine and if I can just get this working I can FINALLY finish this. Any help is incredibly appreciated.

Here's the java file. I think it's clear where the file creation/writing bit is.

```
package com.loch.meaptracker;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.google.ads.*;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnSeekBarChangeListener {

private SeekBar happyBar, energyBar, anxietyBar, painBar;
private EditText noteField;
private DatePicker dPick;
private TimePicker tPick;
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private Button enterButton;
private int happyValue = 4, energyValue = 4, anxietyValue = 4,
        painValue = 4;
private static final String TAG = "heapApp";
private String Mood = "Blah";
private AdView adView;
final Context context = this;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    try {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Create the adView
        adView = new AdView (this, AdSize.BANNER, "a15138b1a7adad2");

        // Lookup your RelativeLayout assuming it's been given the attribute android:id="@+id/AdRelativeLayout
        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.AdRelativeLayout); 

        // Add the AdView to it
        layout.addView(adView);

        // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());

        // bars
        happyBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.happinessBarID);
        happyBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        energyBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.energyBarID);
        energyBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        anxietyBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.anxietyBarID);
        anxietyBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        painBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.painBarID);
        painBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        // end bars
        dPick = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
        tPick = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);
        noteField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.noteTextFieldID);
        enterButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enterButtonID);
    } catch (Exception onCreateException) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception received", onCreateException);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

// Bar listener methods
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int barValue, boolean hFromUser) {
    try {

        switch (arg0.getId()) {
        case R.id.happinessBarID:
            happyValue = barValue + 1;
            break;
        case R.id.energyBarID:
            energyValue = barValue + 1;
            break;
        case R.id.anxietyBarID:
            anxietyValue = barValue + 1;
            break;
        case R.id.painBarID:
            painValue = barValue + 1;
            break;
        }
        String debugBarValue = "Happy is " + happyValue + ", Energy is "
                + energyValue + ", Anxiety is " + anxietyValue
                + ", Pain is " + painValue + ".";
        System.out.println(debugBarValue);

    } catch (Exception BarValueException) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception received", BarValueException);
    }

}

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar happyBar) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar happyBar) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

// end Bar listener methods

// Enter Button listener Method

public void dialogPop(View v) {
    try {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                context);

        // set Title
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("title");

        // set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("You entered: " + getMood())
                .setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("Okay",
                // When Okay button clicked the write mood string to file
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {
                                try {
                                    // This is the string that should be
                                    // written to file
                                    String data = getMood();
                                    // This is the file that should be
                                    // written to
                                    File heapFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "heapFile.csv");

                                    // if file doesn't exists, then create
                                    // it
                                    if (!heapFile.exists()) {
                                        heapFile.createNewFile();
                                        FileWriter heapFileWritter = new FileWriter(
                                                heapFile.getName(), true);
                                        BufferedWriter heapBufferWritter = new BufferedWriter(
                                                heapFileWritter);
                                        heapBufferWritter.write(data);
                                        heapBufferWritter.close();

                                        System.out.println("Done");
                                    }

                                    // true = append file
                                    FileWriter heapFileWritter = new FileWriter(
                                            heapFile.getName(), true);
                                    BufferedWriter heapBufferWritter = new BufferedWriter(
                                            heapFileWritter);
                                    heapBufferWritter.write(data);
                                    heapBufferWritter.close();

                                    System.out.println("Done");

                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }

                        })
                // If they press either the cancel button or the back button
                // on their device (Same thing) then close the dialog and
                // give the user a chance to change what they've entered
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

        // create alert dialog
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

        // show it
        alertDialog.show();
    } catch (Exception buttonListenerException) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception received", buttonListenerException);
    }
    return;
}

public String getMood() {
    try {
        int month = dPick.getMonth();
        int day = dPick.getDayOfMonth();
        int year = dPick.getYear();
        int minute = tPick.getCurrentMinute();
        String moodAntePost = "AM";
        boolean hourType = tPick.is24HourView();
        int moodHour = tPick.getCurrentHour();
        if (hourType == false && moodHour > 12) {
            moodHour = (moodHour - 12);
            moodAntePost = "PM";
        } else if (hourType == false && moodHour <= 0) {
            moodHour = 12;
        } else {
        }
        String noteText = noteField.getText().toString();
        Mood = "Happiness," + happyValue + ",Energy," + energyValue
                + ",Anxiety," + anxietyValue + ",Pain," + painValue
                + ",Date," + month + "/" + day + "/" + year + ",Time,"
                + moodHour + ":" + minute + "," + moodAntePost + ",Note,"
                + noteText;
        System.out.println(Mood);
    } catch (Exception getMoodException) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception received", getMoodException);
    }

    return Mood;
}

}
```

Edited my question to include the manifest so you can see the permissions I've got. I think it's right but I'm not certain...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.loch.meaptracker"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.loch.meaptracker.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Quick question, did you add the permissions for `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`?

Comment: Oh right! Let me edit and include my manifest in the question. Might have borked something in that although I think I do have it right.

Comment: I don't actually need to include permission to read external storage as I never actually need the contents of the file in question. Not yet anyway. I will need to do so in a later version of this program when I include a few other functions I have planned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this:

```
 String file = heapFile.getAbsolutePath();
 FileWriter heapFileWritter = new FileWriter(file, true);
```

getName() would give you just the name of the file. But you need to provide absolutepath for FileWriter.

Comment: Okay well your suggestion worked except for some reason it wrote the string twice. >_<

Comment: *facepalm* I'm an idiot. I see now why it did it twice. Thank you very much. I think this will finish it.

Comment: For anyone out there reading this, it was simply because I neglected to wrap the code after the if {*do this stuff*} in an else {}. Once I did that it worked perfectly.